# (JQuery UI) All content showing at once

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have JQuery and JQuery UI installed just fine, and they both work fine, but when I try to use the tabs feature of JQuery UI, I get all the content showing at once.

I read the documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/
so I know that I am using the correct codes to make it happen.
This is my HTML:
`<div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        <p>This is the content of tab 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <p>Something for tab 2 goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        <p>The content of tab 3 shows up here.</p>
    </div>
</div>`

And this is my code for starting it:
`$(function() {
    $('#tab').tabs();
});`

The only problem is that all the div's are showing up all at the same time.
Below is the photo of what is showing up.
http://derpcast.net/snap/pic18-07-14.png
You can click the tabs just fine, but it doesn't change what is showing up in the box. Can someone help with why the tabs are not showing up correctly.

If noone can help me, I can do it manually, but I just want to get the tabs to work.

Comment: are you including the jquery-ui.js & css files?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you miss to include required jquery libraries and related CSS. Your code works fine.

Refer, `[http://jsfiddle.net/cfs69yxf/]`

Comment: Well, it seems to work if I use a jquery link to get the files. But when I reference a file in the folder for jquery, it doesnt work. But the thing is, the jquery that I am referencing is a lower version than the one that I was using.

Comment: Good that you nailed down the issue!